# What is a trick to use Cloud Function for millions of Users?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I use Firebase Cloud Function on Node.js using Flutter [Dart].

For your information, Firebase only gives a rate limits of 5000 API Calls (READ) per 100 seconds based on this link [Cloud Function's Rate Limits](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/quotas#rate_limits). What I wanna know is if one day my Android app has at least a million users; then how can Firebase handle hundred of thousands API call from users?

I meant, if Firebase has a limit; then why the advertising said that Firebase can expand the limit based on users' requests? I am very sorry if I lack of knowledge, but as far as I know, we cannot raise the limit.

Meanwhile, I read on Scalability on this link [Cloud Function's Scalability](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/quotas#scalability) and it said that this limit is not applied to HTTP Functions which means using HTTP Functions has unlimited quota. I read about HTTP Functions and HTTPS callable function inside Flutter [Dart] is not identical to HTTP Function as stated on this link [HTTPS Callable Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#dart).

So if this HTTPS Callable Function has its limit, then how can it handle millions of Users' request from the app as I will put the whole Intellectual Property on the backend [Firebase]???
A tips and detail information will be great. Thank you, guys.

Comment: As I read it, the limits are for the Cloud Functions API (which are presumably used to manage your Cloud Functions). Firestore, the NoSQL offering within Firebase, has [completely different limits](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#limits).

Comment: @robertklep, Uhm I am talking about Cloud Function here. Since I am gonna use it to derive Intellectual Property from backend. So, I never intended to run any Firestore to read data from client App using Flutter, but from backend to prevent any unexpected call functions.

Comment: Again, as I read it, the rate limits are for Cloud Functions API calls, not for how often your hosted functions can be called.

Comment: Well, if you visit this link below, you'll know that there is a quota for Cloud Function Read Requests per minute which only provide 3000 per minute: https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas

Comment: I guess you answered your own question then.

Comment: So, we need to ask for request to upgrade its quota??? Well, I think they need to change their advertising video specifically for this case. It made me confuse for the mean time. There is no such a thing like: auto-increment quota. We need to request them after all.

Comment: You are confusing API quotas (management APIs) with clients calling your Cloud Function application (HTTP Requests). Cloud Functions supports 3,000 concurrent invocations per second per function.

Comment: @john-hanley - If total clients are 500,000 and all of them call the same Cloud Function at the same time as I put the IP on backend, how do Firebase handle such a thing? Will it stop the 470,000 users' request or is there another solution for this case?

Comment: Your question is theoretical and does not represent real-world design. Yes, your users would receive an error, most likely 429. Your code can detect that, wait and try again. You could deploy more functions. However, I would not use Cloud Functions as my central entry point for a system that handles millions of users. I would deploy large load balancers, Compute Engine instances, Kubernetes, etc. Cloud Functions would handle specific code use cases. When you need a MAC truck, you don't use wheelbarrows.

Comment: @JohnHanley - If I need to use what you suggested above [Cloud Balancing, GCE, etc.], I will contact you later on your website when the total users have reached at least 3000. I think I am gonna apply Cloud Run for this. Let's see later which scenario is the best [Cloud Function or Cloud Run]. I will pay you, of course. Thank you for the tips.

Comment: Cloud Run is an excellent/amazing service and one of my all-time favorites. The new Gen2 of Cloud Functions actually runs on Cloud Run.